# BizTalk 2013R2 Dev Edition Azure Gallery Image - SQL EXPIRED

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I an a MSDN ultimate subscription holder and I have created a virtual machines within Azure from the Gallery.  I have select the BizTalk 2013R2 Developer Edition from the gallery which has initially been great and save me a lot of time with the setup.  Unfortunately after only a couple of weeks my SQL license has expired.

As I did not select any form of evaluation edition I would not expect software licenses to expire when they are provisioned from the gallery whenever.  As I understand it as an MSDN ultimate customer I am covered to license BizTalk Developer Edition and indeed SQL which come as part of the gallery VM.

I've seen a number of posts online around this with no solution and I was wondering if you have a view on this.

Have I picked up the wrong understanding or is their a defect with the BizTalk 2013R2 Developer edition gallery image.  A colleague recently reported the same thing happened with BizTalk 2013R2 standard edition image.

Any help and advice would be appreciate as I am stuck if SQL has expired.  I don't see the point in provisioning a new gallery image if the same problem will happen.

It is very convenient provisioning from the gallery but if the licenses expire then they become less useful and very annoying.  I could understand if I provisioned an evaluation copy but this was not the case here.

Comment: You should really send this as a support request to Azure Support...  What could any of us here do about software licensing issues?

Comment: Ok, can't raise it with azure technical support without paying for the privilege. I think I am only entitled to raise billing queries. Azure support page points to msdn support and stack overview for options of assistance. Obviously I appreciate no one can resolve a licencing issue but wondering had anyone experienced the same issue and if so how did it get resolved. Not being able to raise a valid azure technical call without paying really sucks.

Comment: Looks like you got a response from Microsoft in their forum saying they will be looking into it.  Hopefully they will resolve it soon.

Comment: Guys anyone seeing this thread having this issue should look at my post on MSDN.  It would be great if you could also comment to apply some urgency to this issue.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8b36ede-e968-48a6-b459-1999d4cd347c/biztalk-2013r2-developer-edition-from-gallery-sql-expired?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Based upon your own posts on that social.MSDN thread, it sounds like the solution was to perform an edition upgrade of SQL server to a licensed version. Is that correct?

Comment: Besides MSDN forums, wouldn't your MSDN subscription's support-incident credits cover this?